# Contar valor em uma célula dinâmica do Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma célula no excel que fica alterando de valor automaticamente com base na cotação de uma ação.
o que eu preciso é contar sempre que o valor for alterado.

A função abaixo funciona se chamada somente para um ativo, porém se eu chamar novamente a função para um segundo ativo, as contagens interferem no valor de uma e de outra

```
Private intA As Integer
Private intB As Integer

Function AddSomeNumbers(valor As Integer) As Integer
    
    If valor = 1 And intB = 0 Then
    intA = intA + 1
    intB = 1
    ElseIf valor = 0 And intB = 1 Then
    intA = intA
    intB = 0
    End If
    
    AddSomeNumbers = intA
    
End Function
```

Grato